why i am getting error Import "PyPDF4" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports even after importing?
I have done everything , reinstalled pypdf4 , reloaded vs code but still I get the error Import "PyPDF4" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports.
Though when I check (venv) PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\hrtool>
pip show pypdf4
Name: PyPDF4
Version: 1.27.0
Summary: PDF toolkit
Home-page: http://claird.github.com/PyPDF4
Author: Mathieu Fenniak
Author-email: biziqe@mathieu.fenniak.net
License: 
Location: C:\Users\Administrator\hrtool\venv\Lib\site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: 
(venv) PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\hrtool>

                              

Please help me fix this the code is simple.
from PyPDF4 import PdfReader


reader = PdfReader(pdf_path)
number_of_pages = len(reader.pages)
print(f"Number of pages: {number_of_pages}")

# Optionally, read text from the first page
first_page = reader.pages[0]
text = first_page.extract_text()
print(text)
`


Please use pypdf, not PyPDF4. Those are two different projects. pypdf is very actively developed. PyPDF4 is dead.
